# Use sed to replace all ' with \' and all " with \"

Tags: bash, sed

I want to use sed to replace all `'` with `\'` and all `"` with `\"`. Example input:

```
"a" 'b'
```

Output:

```
\"a\" \'b\'
```

Comment: sed 's/\'\'/g'  (substitute " for ' in my other case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `?` character in your post, but I'll assume your question is "How do I do such a replacement?".  I just made a quick test file with your input, and this command line seems to work:

```
sed -e 's#"#\\"#g' -e "s#'#\\\'#g"
```

Example:

```
$ cat input 
"a" 'b'
$ sed -e 's#"#\\"#g' -e "s#'#\\\'#g" input 
\"a\" \'b\'
```

Comment: I almost upvoted your answer, but I believe in using the default delimiter (`/`) unless there is very good reason not to (e.g., the pattern or replacement contains such a character). Moreover, since `#` is the comment character, I would object to its use even more than using, say, `:` or `,`.

Comment: I don't like using `/` when the pattern contains `\ ` or `/` characters - it's just a recipe for more confusion.  I used `#` here because it's not in the patterns anywhere.  I guess `:` would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

While using `sed` is the portable solution, all this can be done using `Bash`'s builtin string manipulation functions as well.

```
(
#set -xv
#str=$'"a" \'b\''
str='"a" '"'b'"  # concatenate 'str1'"str2"
str="${str//\"/\\\"}"
str="${str//\'/\'}"
echo "$str"
)
```